# Home wifi network (extended) dropping internet connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Just as the title states, my home wifi network drops internet connectivity every once in a while.

Network setup:

1. Modem/Router solution
   Thomson Technicolor Gateway TG799vn v2 (ISP handed it to me)

Standard Gateway: 192.168.1.1

DHCP is activated

DNS through that as well

Channel: Dynamic

2. Wifi Extender

Netgear WN3000RP

Static IP - 192.168.1.85

It's connected to the main network and thereafter creating a network "mynetwork_2"

It has an average link rate of 78 Mbps

Channel is set to automatic.

*I live in a not so crowded place, at tops 8 other networks barely in reach, all of which (as of now) are on channels:*

- 1: Aprox. 1 network
- 6: Aprox. 3 networks
- 11: Aprox. 2 networks

Not sure whether they are dynamically changing channels or not

The main network has never meant any problem, so I would say that that is ruled out.
The extender, though has been grumpy for as long as I can remember (About a month old)

I have tried two different setups, first I tried having the extender network on the same SSID as the main one, the same security type, passphrase and so on to enable a type of seamless overlap of the wifi. This worked, but it was not reliable.

After that I configured it to what it is today. It's connected to the main router and then responsible of its own network - "mynetwork_2" Then I just connect to whatever network suits me best. Firstly I thought this was a problem with the SSIDs that they somehow collided when they were set to the same one, therefore I changed it thinking it would be more reliable. Since then nothing has changed - the internet connectivity still drops every once in a while whilst connected to the extender.

If more information is needed, please request it.

Comment: When Internet connectivity is not working, can you reach the router?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes I can